# send mail from local host with gmail

Tags: php, email, xampp

hi dear i have a problem in sending email from xampp (local host) with gmail
this is my php.ini code==

```
[mail function]
SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
sendmail_from = mail@gmail.com
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

and this is my sendmail.ini

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=arodana5000@gmail.com
auth_password= my password
force_sender=
```

and when I run the PHP file to send the mail it will create new crash file. this is the crash please open it [file](https://fastupload.co/1075761)
please help me

or look at it there

**>         date/time         : 2020-10-29, 14:17:59, 963ms

> ```
> computer name     : MSI
> user name         : Aro dana
> registered owner  : Aro dana
> operating system  : Windows NT New x64 build 9200
> system language   : English
> system up time    : 4 days 14 hours
> program up time   : 845 milliseconds
> processors        : 12x Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz
> physical memory   : 6920/16228 MB (free/total)
> free disk space   : (C:) 9.56 GB (D:) 601.37 GB
> display mode      : 1536x864, 32 bit
> process id        : $20b4
> allocated memory  : 22.45 MB
> executable        : sendmail.exe
> exec. date/time   : 2012-04-16 20:30
> compiled with     : Delphi 2006/07
> madExcept version : 3.0l
> callstack crc     : $1d5da2f6, $c8f19877, $c8f19877
> exception number  : 1
> exception class   : EIdSocketError
> exception message : Socket Error # 11001 Host not found.
>
> main thread ($36ec):
> 00435e23 +0073 sendmail.exe IdStack                        706  +42 TIdStack.RaiseSocketError
> 00433faf +0123 sendmail.exe IdStackWindows                1227  +55 TIdStackWindows.HostByName
> 00435a75 +006d sendmail.exe IdStack                        571  +10 TIdStack.ResolveHost
> 00440a70 +00fc sendmail.exe IdIOHandlerStack               314  +23 TIdIOHandlerStack.ConnectClient
> 0046554d +0031 sendmail.exe IdSSLOpenSSL                  2086   +8 TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.ConnectClient
> 00444a9f +0063 sendmail.exe IdIOHandlerSocket              335  +13 TIdIOHandlerSocket.Open
> 00465637 +0007 sendmail.exe IdSSLOpenSSL                  2122   +1 TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Open
> 0044157d +0235 sendmail.exe IdTCPClient                    318  +53 TIdTCPClientCustom.Connect
> 00445cc8 +00a4 sendmail.exe IdExplicitTLSClientServerBase  257  +23 TIdExplicitTLSClient.Connect
> 0045ab7b +0017 sendmail.exe IdSMTP                         373   +2 TIdSMTP.Connect
> 004b5f14 +1060 sendmail.exe sendmail                       808 +326 initialization
> 77036357 +0017 KERNEL32.DLL                                         BaseThreadInitThunk
>
> thread $5414:
> 77036357 +17 KERNEL32.DLL  BaseThreadInitThunk
>
> thread $7080:
> 77036357 +17 KERNEL32.DLL  BaseThreadInitThunk
>
> thread $6164:
> 77036357 +17 KERNEL32.DLL  BaseThreadInitThunk
>
> stack dump:
> 0019fc58  28 5e 43 00 de fa ed 0e - 01 00 00 00 07 00 00 00  (^C.............
> 0019fc68  6c fc 19 00 28 5e 43 00 - 08 cc 45 02 ec 28 43 00  l...(^C...E..(C.
> 0019fc78  30 50 45 02 f9 2a 00 00 - a8 fc 19 00 88 fc 19 00  0PE..*..........
> 0019fc88  b0 fc 19 00 c8 4b 40 00 - a8 fc 19 00 00 00 00 00  .....K@.........
> 0019fc98  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - f9 2a 00 00 30 50 45 02  .........*..0PE.
> 0019fca8  f4 fc 19 00 b2 3f 43 00 - 1c fd 19 00 c8 4b 40 00  .....?C......K@.
> 0019fcb8  f4 fc 19 00 44 fd 19 00 - 4b 02 00 00 ec 28 43 00  ....D...K....(C.
> 0019fcc8  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00  ................
> 0019fcd8  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
> 0019fce8  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 10 fd 19 00  ................
> 0019fcf8  77 5a 43 00 3c fd 19 00 - 00 00 00 00 ff ff ff 00  wZC.<...........
> 0019fd08  a8 a9 46 02 30 50 45 02 - 48 fd 19 00 75 0a 44 00  ..F.0PE.H...u.D.
> 0019fd18  3c fd 19 00 50 fd 19 00 - c8 4b 40 00 48 fd 19 00  <...P....K@.H...
> 0019fd28  14 3f 41 00 b0 f4 3e 02 - b0 f4 3e 02 90 69 44 02  .?A...>...>..iD.
> 0019fd38  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 b0 f4 3e 02  ..............>.
> 0019fd48  64 fd 19 00 52 55 46 00 - 78 fd 19 00 c8 4b 40 00  d...RUF.x....K@.
> 0019fd58  64 fd 19 00 14 3f 41 01 - b0 f4 3e 02 ac fd 19 00  d....?A...>.....
> 0019fd68  a5 4a 44 00 b0 f4 3e 02 - 3c 56 46 00 83 15 44 00  .JD...>.<VF...D.
> 0019fd78  84 fd 19 00 5f 4d 40 00 - ac fd 19 00 d8 fd 19 00  ...._M@.........
> 0019fd88  c8 4b 40 00 ac fd 19 00 - 14 3f 41 00 b0 f4 3e 02  .K@......?A...>.
>
> disassembling:
> [...]
> 00435e13       push    eax
> 00435e14       mov     ecx, [ebp-8]
> 00435e17       mov     dl, 1
> 00435e19       mov     eax, [$4352ac]
> 00435e1e       call    -$717 ($43570c)        ; IdStack.EIdSocketError.CreateError
> 00435e23     > call    -$3113c ($404cec)      ; System.@RaiseExcept
> 00435e28 707   xor     eax, eax
> 00435e2a       pop     edx
> 00435e2b       pop     ecx
> 00435e2c       pop     ecx
> 00435e2d       mov     fs:[eax], edx
> [...]**
> ```

Comment: most likely, no one is going to download and open that file. better to just include the relevant message here as text

Answer (score 0):

in the google account you have to disable security for 3rd party apps in order to send emails via that account. or create special app password for that, otherwise google will not let you send that email.
https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en

Comment: hi I think you are right please where can I disable it

Comment: can you check this: https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps but pls check all information this is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

**Symptoms**

There are issues connecting to a remote Host:

- Host status is shown as "Offline" in the Viewer address book.
- You can establish a remote connection, but the connection is unstable.

When you examine the Host log you see the following error: `Socket Error # 11001 Host not found.(EIdSocketError)`

**Cause**

This issue applies to Internet-ID connection. When this connection type is in use, the program communicates with an intermediary server on the web — depending on your settings this can be our public server or a self-hosted server that you maintain.

This error might mean that the remote Host is unavailable due to one of these reasons:

- DNS problem, i.e. the IP address of the intermediary server cannot be resolved from its DNS name.
- The intermediary server's address and/or outbound port is blocked in the firewall.

To resolve the issue, please try the solutions below in the order they are listed.

**Step 1**

Clear DNS cache on the computer where the Host is installed (the steps below apply to Windows 10):

1. Press Win + R to open the Run dialog.
2. Type ipconfig /flushdns and click OK (or hit Enter):Flush DNS
3. A command box will flash on the screen for a split second and the DNS cache is cleared.
4. Right click on the Host icon in the tray area and select Restart Host. Wait 10-20 seconds until the Host restarts and establishes a connection to the intermediary server.

**Step 2**

If you use our public Internet-ID service make sure that the primary server at `id.remoteutilities.com` can be accessed from the Host PC and the IP address of the server can be resolved successfully.

1. Press Win + R to open the Run dialog.
2. Type cmd and click OK (or hit Enter). The Command Prompt will open.
3. Type ping id.remoteutilities.com and hit Enter.
4. If the ping command and DNS resolution are successful you should see the result as in the image below:Ping ID server
5. If you receive "Request timed out" as a response, the ID server cannot be reached from the Host location. Please, contact your system administrator.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow other application usage on your google accounts because your account does not let to undefined app request.
[Gmail Application Allow](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en)
allow